# Reading efficiently PATHs in Vim

Tags: vim, path

**How can you open the following PATH by `ctrl-w-f` to a new window?**

Path

```
 /usr/masi/codes/11
```

The PATH refers to a file `11.tex`.
I need to use `11` instead of `11.tex`
because my LaTeX or pdflatex does not understand PATHs with tex
when I input/include the file.

Possible solutions are

- to add something to .vimrc
- to use perhaps differently `pdflatex`

Comment: Could you explain more? ctrl-w-f is working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Vim 7.2, you can set the suffixesadd to .txt as below:

```
:set suffixesadd=.tex,.latex,.java
```

see `:help suffixesadd`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you'll need to override CTRL-W_f to add a extension.
For instance, you could add the following in a tex-ftplugin:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <c-w>f :exe ':sp '.globpath('.', expand('<cfile>').'.*')<cr>
```

NB: this mapping is far from perfection. It's still need to glob on , and .*, to keep only one file (or none) if several match. And to support the no-match case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about latex to answer from its side, but I don't see a setting to make Vim look for the path with extensions, so you will have to create a custom mapping. Unfortunately, there are no command-line equivalents to the gf and f style of commands, so you have to mimic something equivalent (sorry, untested).

```
function! OpenFile()
  try
    exec "normal! \<C-W>f"
  except
    if filereadable(expand('<cfile>').'.tex')
      split <cfile>.tex
    endif
  endtry
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> <C-W>f :call OpenFile()<CR>
```

You can put this in an ftplugin (with  option for nnoremap) to restrict it to your latex files only.

Note: If you want to cover different cases such as gf, F, you will need a more sophisticated function, or just write different functions for each.

Answer (score 0):

I use vim 7.2 and it really works with default settings. If i understand the problem well.
It works with soft link and hard link both.